# Form to Table using VBA Macro's in Microsoft Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, transfer

I am trying to fill in a form and when I click the add button it goes and inserts it into my table.

The form is called `frmClients` and the table is called `Clients`. I have several fields that I need to transfer from the form to the table.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simply place a button on the form, and use this code:

```
If me.Dirty = true then
   Me.Dirty = false
End if
```

The above will send the values in textboxes to the table that the form is based on.